# How to make two buttons into one?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have two buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="foo">off</button>
<button type="button" id="bar">on</button>
```

and I have a console that is logging every 1 second "on":

```
function disable() {
    console.log("on");
}

window.setInterval(function () {
    disable();
}, 1000);
```

the `#foo` button stops the log like so:

```
$("#foo").click(function () {
    window.disable = function () {
        //aborted
    };
});
```

and the `#bar` button continues the log like so:

```
    $("#bar").click(function () {
        window.disable = function disable() {
            console.log("on");
        };
    });
```

## See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sEbZ7/)

---

I want to be able to make both buttons become one by using a toggle

---

I have tried this. But it just makes the button disappear?!!

```
    $("#target").click(function () {
        $(this).toggle(function () {
            window.disable = function () {
                //aborted
            };
        }, function () {
            window.disable = function disable() {
                console.log("on");
            };
        });
    });
```

---

## Why is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy7mE/) not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

<button type="button" class="foo">off</button>

<button type="button2" class="bar"<on>/button>

<button type="button" id="fop"<toggle>/button>

```
function disable() {
console.log("on");
}

window.setInterval(function () {
  disable();
}, 1000);

$(document).ready(function () {
   var flag=true;
 $("#fop").click(function () {
     flag=flag?false:true;
    if(flag){
        $('.foo').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('.bar').removeAttr('disabled');
      $(".foo").click();
    }else{ 
       $('.bar').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('.foo').removeAttr('disabled');
       $(".bar").click();
    };
});


$(".foo").on("click",function () {
    window.disable = function () {
        //aborted
    };
});

$(".bar").on("click",function () {
    window.disable = function disable() {
        console.log("on");
    };
});
});
```

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Akhlesh/Zy7mE/1/)

Comment: @Maximilian but without clearInterval how can you stop the setInterval.I think you are looking for something like publisher subscriber kind of thing.

Comment: @Maximilian is this correct solution or you need something else?

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. Watch the console on jsfiddle!

Comment: it is working when on is disabled logging is on and when off is disabled it means logging is off.

but on load by default it is on.

Answer (score 0):

`toggle` is deprecated in later versions of jQuery. I think the correct and easier to read version of your code would be setting the timer to a variable, and flag to whether the timer is running. Check that flag, and clear or enable the timer:

```
function disable() {
    console.log("on");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer = false;

    $("#foo").click(function () {
        if (timer) { 
            clearTimeout(timer)
            timer = false;
        } else {
            timer = setInterval(disable, 1000);
            timer = true;
        }
    });    
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="foo">toggle</button>
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sEbZ7/2/

Comment: That isn't really what I am after

Comment: I literally want when click the first time act like clicking `#foo`. And when clicking the second time act like clicking on `#bar` and so on...

Comment: So the first time turn the timer off, then the next time turn the timer on?